# How to run PIP and Python file together

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to run two batch files one which install two packages using Pip statements and other where are I am running normal python code which uses this package.

First batch file `pip_install_pymysql_vaderSentiment.bat`, has the following statements:

```
cd C:\Users\GOQii-Anoop\Anaconda3\Scripts\
pip install vaderSentiment
pip install pymysql
```

The second batch file `BatchFile_SentimentAnalysis.bat`, invokes the above bat file and installs the packages but it still gives me: `error NoModule name <vaderSentiment>`.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call([r'D:\Anoop\ReviewSentimentAnalysis\pip_install_pymysql_vaderSentiment.bat'])
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer 
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
```

Please let me know why it is giving me error. I wish to automate my python code with click of a button.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the output of `pip_install_pymysql_vaderSentiment.bat`?

Comment: Python is importing `vaderSentiment ` at startup and keeps imports in a cache.

Comment: @CumminUp07 Hello Cummin , It says "requirement already satisfied" when the pip tries to install both the packages,but when the python file runs by calling the second files it says "No Module name : vaderSentiment "

Comment: @MauriceMeyer : How do i rectify this and make it run?,because if I run pip commands in my .py script it runs fine when i manually run it but when i run through a bat file it gives me error on the pip commands

Comment: That makes me think that you may be operating in two different enviroments, especially seeing as how your ouput is saying that it's already installed.